# How do I write values parsed from a CSV file to a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I want to write values parsed from a CSV file to a YAML file:

```
home_phone = row['HomePhone']
 if home_phone.length == 10  
  puts "First Name: #{row['first_Name']} - Home Phone: #{home_phone} -  Zip Code: #{zip_code}"
  elsif home_phone.length == 11 && home_phone.start_with?('1')   
  home_phone.slice!(0)
      puts "First Name: #{row['first_Name']} - Home Phone: #{home_phone} -  Zip Code: #{zip_code}"   
  else  
      puts "First Name: #{row['first_Name']} - Home Phone: #{"0000000000"} -  Zip Code: #{zip_code}"      
  end
```

The above code is used for printing the details row-wise. The output obtained from the code is:

```
First Name: Douglas - Home Phone: 4252745000 -  Zip Code: 50309'

'First Name: Aya - Home Phone: 9995901339 -  Zip Code: 90210'

'First Name: Audrey - Home Phone: 0 -  Zip Code: 05667'
```

How can I write these values to a YAML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert a CSV file to YAML...

I created a file called "test.csv" which looks like:

```
First Name,Home Phone,Zip Code
Douglas,4252745000,50309
Aya,9995901339,90210
Audrey,0,05667
```

Using this code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'yaml'

csv = CSV.read('test.csv')
File.write('test.yaml', csv.to_yaml)
pp YAML.load_file('test.yaml')
```

Which generates:

```
---
- - First Name
  - Home Phone
  - Zip Code
- - Douglas
  - '4252745000'
  - '50309'
- - Aya
  - '9995901339'
  - '90210'
- - Audrey
  - '0'
  - '05667'
```

I get this output from `pp` showing a correct round-trip of the CSV data through YAML-land:

```
[["First Name", "Home Phone", "Zip Code"],
 ["Douglas", "4252745000", "50309"],
 ["Aya", "9995901339", "90210"],
 ["Audrey", "0", "05667"]]
```

This is just a simple solution, which loads the entire CSV file into memory. That's not a scalable solution if you are processing files bigger than the available RAM on your system. CSV supports `foreach` which will let you read the file line by line, but YAML might find it difficult to write the file line-by-line because of how it generates the file; It expects a complete hash or array, but you'll be passing it sub-arrays, which will result in a YAML file looking like:

```
---
- - First Name
  - Home Phone
  - Zip Code
---
- - Douglas
  - '4252745000'
  - '50309'
---
- - Aya
  - '9995901339'
  - '90210'
---
- - Audrey
  - '0'
  - '05667'
```

Loading that with `YAML.load_file` will result in:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] "First Name",
        [1] "Home Phone",
        [2] "Zip Code"
    ]
]
```

In other words, only the first row will be returned.

The workaround is to use `YAML.load_documents(File.open('test.yaml', 'r'))` instead of `load_file`, which reassembles the parts into one array again.

Answer (score 0):

If your row data is a hash (which it looks to be), try using [to_yaml](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/syck/rdoc/Hash.html#method-i-to_yaml) like this:

```
File.open(<path to your output file here>, "w") { |f| f.write(row.to_yaml) }
```

You can then read it like so:

```
YAML.load_file(<path to your output file here>)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'yaml'
File.open('somefile.yaml','w') do |f|
  f.write(row['first_Name'])
  f.write(row['home_phone'])
  f.write(row['zip_code'])
end
```

Comment: This won't generate YAML at all.